# React Native: Creating a Switch Navigator using React Navigation v5

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

I had my authentication workflow working using a Switch Navigator and then I would use "props.navigation.navigate()" to switch to a different screen or navigator.

I'm using the Switch navigator because I don't want the user to be able to click back between these places:

```
MainNavigator(Switch Navigator)
    - Splash (Screen) 

    - Auth (Stack Navigator)
        -Login (Screen)
        -Register (Screen)

    - Tutorial (Stack Navigator)
        -Tutorial Page 1 (Screen)
        -Tutorial Page 2 (Screen)
        -Tutorial Page 3 (Screen)

    - App (Drawer Navigator)
        -All screens for app

1-First Splash screen loads everything and check if there is an auth token inside the local storage.
2-If token found then "navigate('App')" if token not found then "navigate('Auth')"
3-If user register successfully then "navigate('Tutorial')"
4-At the end of the tutorial "navigate('App')"
```

The problem comes when I try to do the same thing using React Navigation v5. It seems that they have removed the Switch navigator and in their documentation, they only show one example of using a 
"isLoggedIn" state to switch between 2 different navigators.

Any ideas or suggestions?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

[React Navigation v5 supports a compatibility layer](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/compatibility/) which exposes a Switch Navigator.

> npm install @react-navigation/compat

```
import { createSwitchNavigator } from "@react-navigation/compat";

const AppNavigator = createSwitchNavigator({
    "splash": { screen: SplashScreen, },
    "home": HomeNavigator,
    "login": AuthNavigator,
},
{
    initialRouteName: "splash",
});

function App() {
    return (
        <NavigationContainer>
            <AppNavigator />
        </NavigationContainer>   
    );
}

export default App;
```

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/compatibility/

Comment: Thanks, I found that if I simply use a Stack navigator and use the "replace()" method instead of "navigate()" it works the same way since it prevents the user from going back.